# How to guard nestjs swagger endpoint

Tags: javascript, authentication, swagger, nestjs

How would you go about guarding swagger docs on nestjs as swagger module setup happens on the main.ts file.

```
 const options = new DocumentBuilder()
      .setTitle("API")
      .setDescription("NestJS api")
      .setVersion("1.0")
      .build();
    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
    SwaggerModule.setup("swagger", app, document);
```

I am looking to use a guard like below to the swagger docs endpoint.

```
@UseGuards(RolesGuard)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [Interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) if you want to stay in NestJS design

Or you can use `express` or `fastify` authentication middleware in app `bootstrap` method, see [this ticket](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/244) for inspiration (old NestJS version)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing just swagger header problem after completing this [NestJs process](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication). if yes then you just have to add `.addBearerAuth()` to the swagger configuration option like this:

```js
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle('REST API BY NEST')
  .setDescription('ITS A REST API')
  .setVersion('1.0')
  .addBearerAuth()
  //You can also add this to .addBearerAuth({type:'http', scheme: 'bearer',  bearerFormat: 'JWT', in:'header'})
  .build();
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
```

After doing this you need to add `@ApiBearerAuth()` Swagger Decorator Before `@UseGuards(AuthGuard)` Like this:

```js
@ApiBearerAuth()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @Get('profile')
  getProfile(@Request() req) {
    const user= this.userService.findAll();
    return user;
  }
```

Or you can add to a overall controller Like this:

```js
@ApiBearerAuth()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Post()
  create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    return this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
  }
```

Now everything is fine Run the API